# Why did Russia and China veto the recent UN resolution for a ceasefire?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, china, 2023-israel-hamas-war, unsc

[Reuters reported](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/un-security-council-fails-pass-us-resolution-calling-immediate-ceasefire-gaza-2024-03-22/) that Russia and China vetoed the UN resolution proposed by US for a ceasefire in the Israel-Hamas war.

Given that their apparent stance was pro-ceasefire recently (just like the demands of people being pro-Palestine), why have Russia and China now vetoed this ceasefire resolution?

Comment: "from the news" Please add a link to the news. "stance was pro-ceasefire recently" A link to that would also be nice. Just for making a nice question that also shines in the future.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The resolution [did not explicitly call for a ceasefire](https://apnews.com/article/united-nations-us-vote-gaza-ceasefire-resolution-f6453803b3eacc9fbaa2ce5a025e2a94).

Its phrasing was [as follows](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/whatsinblue/2024/03/the-middle-east-including-the-palestinian-question-vote-on-a-draft-resolution-4.php):

> Determines the imperative of an immediate and sustained ceasefire to protect civilians on all sides, allow for the delivery of essential humanitarian assistance, and alleviate humanitarian suffering, and towards that end unequivocally supports ongoing international diplomatic efforts to secure such a ceasefire in connection with the release of all remaining hostages;

If you analyze this sentence in legal terms, the first part of it is a perfunctory clause. The action clause instead *supports diplomatic efforts to trade a ceasefire for the release of hostages*.

This language effectively [reinforces Israel's position](https://responsiblestatecraft.org/us-ceasefire-gaza-un/) of linking ceasefire and hostage release demands, with no obligation on either side to actually agree to such a deal, only to keep talking, which they already are.

Apparently, Russia and China [want an unequivocal resolution](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/un-security-council-fails-pass-us-resolution-calling-immediate-ceasefire-gaza-2024-03-22/) that doesn't lead to a second round of debates on whether to call for a ceasefire, for what duration, on what terms, and to what extent.

> Russia's ambassador said the U.S.-led resolution was "exceedingly politicized" and contained an effective green light for Israel to mount a military operation in Rafah

This has happened before, with non-US resolutions [generally calling for an immediate ceasefire](https://apnews.com/article/un-israel-palestinians-gaza-ceasefire-resolution-vote-350c86ef261bf1a00a2515cf22764de5) and getting [vetoed by the US](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/2/21/world-condemns-uss-latest-un-security-council-veto-on-gaza-ceasefire), and vice versa, US resolutions getting vetoed by others.

[image]

France is also drafting its own version. But unless the US decides in favor of an unconditional ceasefire, or China and Russia a conditional one, any passable resolution at this point would have to sidestep the matter, addressing aid and other issues. [There are lengthy negotiations](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/whatsinblue/2024/03/the-middle-east-including-the-palestinian-question-vote-on-a-draft-resolution-4.php) in their preparation.

The previous draft resolutions' full text is as follows:

- [Brazil, 18.10.2023](https://digitallibrary.un.org/nanna/record/4024576/files/S_2023_773-EN.pdf?withWatermark=0&withMetadata=0&version=1&registerDownload=1)
- [Algeria, 20.02.2024](https://file:///C:/Users/vault/Downloads/S_2024_173-EN.pdf)
- The US resolution's full text [appears to be yet unavailable](https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?ln=en&p=&f=&action_search=Search&c=Resource%20Type&c=UN%20Bodies&sf=latest%20first&so=d&rg=50&fti=0&fct__2=Security%20Council&fct__1=Draft%20Resolutions%20and%20Decisions) at the UN website. It might become available later.

From these previous drafts, one can see that many perfunctory clauses, broadly reiterating the UN's values, are typical of UN resolutions. Only a some clauses, normally beginning with "Calls" or "Demands", are worded as guidance for action.

Edit: A new resolution [has been passed](https://news.un.org/en/story/2024/03/1147931) on March 25. Russia and China supported it and the US abstained.

This resolution demands Israel to cease its offensive for a month and Hamas to release the hostages. This is how UN resolutions are normally worded: *"A should do X and B should do Y"*, rather than as a call for negotiations.

Comment: Good answer, but keep in mind that there is limited if any direct enforcement mechanism on resolutions - absent armed coercion - so the exact legalese meaning may be less factually relevant than would be the case on a traditional contract.  To a large extent this might have been "good enough" - and I suspect Russia and China are less concerned with Palestinian welfare than grandstanding at US expense.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That's true. But this lack of enforcement is also why the UN can and often does use the strongest language possible, like calling for immediate permanent peace, knowing it gets toned down a lot in the implementation.

Comment: Meh, a more charitable [reading](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-68627272) is that it proposed a ceasefire only *after* the hostages were released, i.e. that it was a conditional call for ceasefire. Anyway Russia and China said the wording was at the very least confusing.

Comment: "Apparently, Russia and China want an unequivocal resolution" Have they said that somewhere? It might be true, but saying it directly is stronger than only hinting towards it.

Comment: By the way, the U.S. resolution designated Hamas as a terrorist organization, which is unacceptable to many countries.

Comment: The UN's site is extremely frustrating.  For all the money they probably spend on the website, and all the verbiage they expend talking about said [resolution](https://press.un.org/en/2024/sc15637.doc.htm) and [again](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/whatsinblue/2024/03/the-middle-east-including-the-palestinian-question-vote-on-a-draft-resolution-4.php), where is the &^#S@! full text?  I can just imagine the vast teams of bureaucrat-programmers in charge of this.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica It appears there's a delay in publishing these documents, ranging from a week to a couple weeks.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: it will be linked here https://research.un.org/en/docs/sc/quick/meetings/2024 (as S/2024/239). For  now it gives and ODS error, which means the doc is not yet up. I'm not sure why they need so long to up it. Stuff from last week on Afghanistan is up though. And even stuff from Monday on Haiti. Weekend I guess. 22 was a Friday.

Comment: @thegodsfromengineering Yes, I've asked resolution "full text of resolution" questions here before and also found it strange then that they are so slow posting them.  How are nations' electorates supposed to know if their countries are acting in good faith @ UN if the news reports are based on official feedback but the text is not there?  Yet, they had the time to put up 2 pages *discussing* the resolution that they are too incompetent (it's just a damn CMS, folks) to post right away.  Sorry, not generally a UN-hater but this does not do much good for transparency.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution In their speeches explaining the vote, several countries mentioned their support and expectations for the next resolution.
see: https://english.almayadeen.net/news/politics/unsc-to-vote-on-another-ceasefire-resolution-for-gaza-on-sat

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica but the lack of an enforcement mechanism could also easily be used as an argument to the US to include this stronger language.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: overtaken by events, LOL https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-68658973?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=twitter&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=6601af56683d4b45f938029f%26The%20US%20has%20%27abandoned%20its%20position%27%3A%20Netanyahu%27s%20statement%20in%20full%262024-03-25T17%3A07%3A35.051Z&ns_fee=0&pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:d33d7653-634f-414c-ada7-9923911d7757&pinned_post_asset_id=6601af56683d4b45f938029f&pinned_post_type=share

Comment: Well, now we can are argue about the new one's text.  Though apparently it has been posted on wikipedia.

Answer (score 20):

The ceasefire proposal was conditional and required Hamas to release the hostages first. Sides that voted against demand the ceasefire not to be conditional. As The Russian deputy ambassador to the UN, Dmitry Polyanskiy, said ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/mar/22/us-gaza-ceasefire-resolution-explainer?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_Other)):

> the demand for an immediate ceasefire should not be conditional on the release of hostages or the condemnation of Hamas.

Comment: As usual, it would help to have the resolution's full text - damn press is soooo lazy in that regard - because if what you say is true, then it makes sense not to tie a temporary ceasefire to stop a famine to a hostage release.  So we are all left guessing which country is being the least deceitful in their biased interpretation of an unseen text.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - I don't think either side is being deceitful in their desire for a ceasefire *on terms that suit their goals*.

Answer (score 12):

China [said](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/3/22/un-security-council-does-not-pass-us-resolution-calling-for-gaza-ceasefire) the language was "ambiguous".

> China’s representative, Zhang Jun, said the draft “dodged the most central issue, that of a ceasefire” through its “ambiguous” language.
>
> “Nor does it even provide an answer to the question of realising a ceasefire in the short term,” he added.

Xinhua quoted a bit [more](https://english.news.cn/20240323/eff8f47100254ac58fde7b0a1c3b81f5/c.html) from their ambassador. An additional stated concern was that the US draft resolution didn't condemn the planned/announced Israeli operation in Rafah.

> The ambassador pointed out that the U.S. draft was "unbalanced in many aspects," especially concerning Israel's recent repeated declarations of planning military attacks on Rafah.
>
> "The draft did not clearly oppose such actions, sending a very wrong signal with serious consequences," the ambassador added.

Comment: The Chinese understand English better than the person who drafted the resolution, if the text quoted in Therac's answer is correct. "Determines the imperative..." what?

Comment: @Wastrel: IIRC, the UNSC drafts get translated to the UN [official languages](https://www.un.org/en/our-work/official-languages) before being voted on. China probably looked at the version in Chinese too.

Answer (score 5):

> Russia and China vetoed a UN Security Council resolution on Gaza
> proposed by the United States – with Russia’s envoy calling it “an
> effective green light for Israel to mount a military operation in
> Rafah.

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/liveblog/2024/3/22/israels-war-on-gaza-live-the-choice-is-clear-a-2-state-solution

It seems that Russia believes that the resolution was worded in a way to give an effective green light for Israel to mount a military operation in Rafah. If the Russians believe this, then it wouldn't be surprising that China also believe that this is the case.